# Named Pipe Server in C++ using Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, windows, boost-asio, named-pipes

I've been using the Windows API directly to create a named pipe server as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    // Define the name of the named pipe
    const wchar_t* pipeName = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\MyNamedPipe";

    // Create the named pipe
    HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        pipeName,                  // Pipe name
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,        // Pipe open mode
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT, // Pipe mode
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,  // Number of instances
        512,                       // Output buffer size
        512,                       // Input buffer size
        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,  // Timeout for client connection
        nullptr                    // Security attributes
    );

    if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cerr << "Error creating named pipe. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Wait for a client to connect
    if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, nullptr)) {
        std::cout << "Client connected. Waiting for data...\n";

        // Read data from the client
        char buffer[512];
        DWORD bytesRead;
        if (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead, nullptr)) {
            std::cout << "Received data from client: " << buffer << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Error reading from pipe. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }

        // Disconnect the pipe
        DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Error waiting for client connection. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    // Close the pipe handle
    CloseHandle(hPipe);

    return 0;
}
```

This code is working but it would be nice to use a [`Boost.Asio`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) or similar modern C++ solution. All code I found online either doesn't cover this use case or will not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;

int main() {
    io_service ioService;

    // Define the name of the named pipe
    const char* pipeName = "\\\\.\\pipe\\MyNamedPipe";

    // Create a local endpoint
    local::stream_protocol::endpoint endpoint(pipeName);

    // Create and open the acceptor
    local::stream_protocol::acceptor acceptor(ioService, endpoint);

    std::cout << "Waiting for client connection...\n";

    // Wait for a client to connect
    local::stream_protocol::socket socket(ioService);
    acceptor.accept(socket);

    std::cout << "Client connected. Waiting for data...\n";

    // Read data from the client
    char buffer[512];
    size_t bytesRead = socket.read_some(buffer, ioService); // Error 'boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::local::stream_protocol,boost::asio::any_io_executor>::read_some': no matching overloaded function found

    std::cout << "Received data from client: " << std::string(buffer, bytesRead) << std::endl;

    // Close the socket (automatically disconnects the client)
    socket.close();

    return 0;
}
```

My Boost is version `1.82.0#1` installed via [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io). Any help to get the Boost example to compile and running successfully is much appreciated.

Comment: Doess this help https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/windows/stream_handle.html - UNIX domain sockets are something else. Also see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/process/reference.html#header.boost.process.pipe_hpp

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, [`local::stream_protocol` is for UNIX domain sockets](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/local.html). They're POSIX specific.

Instead, you want to use [Windows stream oriented handles](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/windows/stream_handle.html).

After that, `read_some` function is [documented](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some.html) with the following overloads:

```
template<typename MutableBufferSequence>
    size_t read_some(const MutableBufferSequence & buffers);
template<typename MutableBufferSequence>
    size_t read_some(const MutableBufferSequence & buffers, error_code & ec);
```

First off, the raw character array is not a buffer sequence, and it's completely unclear to me why you were stuffing the service into the last parameter.

Here's fixed:

```
char buffer[512];
size_t bytesRead = socket.read_some(asio::buffer(buffer));
```

In fact, I'd avoid the C-style raw arrays:

```
std::array<char, 512> buffer;
size_t bytesRead = socket.read_some(asio::buffer(buffer));
```

Loose notes:

- Don't "using namespace" indiscriminately. It's a bad idea. Especially since you're definining symbols that conflict with those declared inside `boost::asio` (which explicit allow for ADL as well).
- Don't use the deprecated `io_service`, but the newer `io_context` instead
- Accepting is not a thing for named pipes, as far as I know (pipes are 2-sided streams)

Comment: Sadly I still couldn't compile the full example with Boost.Asio but your answer helped a bit. Maybe you can try and do it yourself if you have Boost.Asio installed since it's not too much to ask I suppose. Due to the lack of example code on how to do this, named pipes might not be intended to be implemented with Boost.Asio, huh?

Comment: You know I've put more than a little effort in this, and yes I compiled all the code I've shown. I know, because at first I misunderstood the question and didn't realize you were after something else. So I'll make you a different proposition: post a new question with the actual, relevant code and I'll fix any problems I see